# ListSelectionListener for many jtables

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have 2 questions for this
**First question**:
What's the best way (in terms of performance) to add a `ListSelectionListner` event to `JTable`.
This:

```
myTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(this);
```

Or this:

```
myTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

                //Do my stiff here...

                }
            }
        });
```

**Second question:**
I have this code:

```
myFirstTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(this);
mySecondTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(this);
```

How can I know the JTable that fired the `ListSelectionListner` event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Part 1

Irrelevant, neither is better or worse from the perspective of performance, it will come down to needs. Obviously if you have a single listener added to multiple tables it would be more efficient from a memory point of view

Which you would use would come down to needs and what you are trying to achieve

## Part 2

Use the ListSelectionEvent#getSource method to determine what actually triggered the event

Comment: Thnx for your answer.